# Vertical Scroll Indicator

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to create a Scroll Indicator, which would not be horizontal, but vertical. The problem is that when I try to start scrolling the bar that indicated the position isn't scaling...

HTML

```html
<div id="scrollbar">
  <div id="bar">
  </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```css
#scrollbar
{
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#scrollbar #bar
{
  width: inherit;
  height: 0%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

JS

```js
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
window.onscroll = function () { scrollIndicator() };
window.onload = function () { scrollIndicator() };
function scrollIndicator()
{
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = 100;
    if(height > 0)
    {
        scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    }
    bar.style.height = scrolled + "%";
}
```

I absolutely cannot find the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your web page doesn't have enough content for it to scroll, hence scroll event isn't firing.

You need to fix the html, `#scrollbar` is missing a closing `div` tag and add enough content on the webpage so that it scrolls.

You also need to change the `width` of `#bar` from `inherit` to `100%`.

```js
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollIndicator()
};

function scrollIndicator() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = 100;
  
  if (height > 0) {
    scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  }

  bar.style.height = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
#scrollbar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#scrollbar #bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.section:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}

.section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollbar">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the width of #bar needed to be changed from `inherit` to `100%`

Comment: I tested it on a website that had enough content to be scrolled. Changing inherit to 100% worked for me perfectly. When I think about it, it makes total sense. It was working, but I couldn't see it because it was only 1% from 1% of the page.